# Error with CART: Layer error: Property 'LandCover' of feature '1_1_1_1_0_0' is missing

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I've been trying to run this code on Google Earth Engine, however I get the following error and I'm not sure how I can resolve this issue:

[image]

```
//Set map centre
Map.setCenter(159.9737, -9.4336, 12.5)

//Import Sentinel-2 Imagery
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2021-01-01')
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))

//clip to region of interest
var median = S2.median();
var clipped = median.clip(roi);

//add different visualisations to map
Map.addLayer(clipped, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 301.55555555555554, max: 2162}, 'True Colour')
Map.addLayer(clipped, {bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3'], min: 215.9245283018868, max: 4181.5}, 'False Colour')
Map.addLayer(clipped, {bands: ['B12', 'B8', 'B4'], min: 68.14285714285714, max: 3633}, 'SWIR')

//add NDVI to map
var maskcloud1 = function(image) {
var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1));
};

var addNDVI = function(image) {
return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']));
};

var S2 = S2.map(addNDVI);

var NDVI = S2.select(['nd']);
var NDVI = NDVI.median();

var ndvi_pal = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];

Map.addLayer(NDVI.clip(roi), {min:-0.5, max:0.9, palette: ndvi_pal}, 'NDVI');

//merge training points
var points = Water.merge(BuiltUp).merge(Road).merge(TreeShrub).merge(GrassBare)
print(points,'points');


var bands = ["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B10","B11","B12"];
var label = 'LandCover';

//sample training points to generate training data
var training = clipped.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: points,
  properties: ['LC'],
  scale: 30
});

print(training, 'training');

//train a CART classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train({
features: training,
classProperty: "LandCover",
inputProperties: bands});

//run final classification
var classified_image = clipped.select(bands).classify(classifier); 

print(classifier,'classifier')

Map.addLayer(classified_image, {palette: ['blue','green', 'red']},
'Classified');
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot reproduce your error without a functioning script, perhaps include your assets or featuers that you are using. But most likely your error is related to: `classProperty: "LandCover"` inside the `.train()` function. You are most likely going to have to change that property to `'LC'` or the properties you have in in your `featureCollection()` called `'training'`

Comment: Changing the classProperty to 'LC' seemed to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference it is helpful if you accept the answer, glad it worked

Comment: same line of codes for another image not working 'LC' in the above error. i tried                                                                      var training = Sentinel_crop.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection:points, 
  properties: ['LC'], 
  scale: 20
});
var classifier= ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features: training, 
  classProperty: 'LC',
  inputProperties: bands});
//print(classifier)
//Classifying the input imagery
var classification= Sentinel_crop.select(bands).classify(classifier)